# Where do I place my nether portals so they don't collide?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am having trouble placing my nether-side portals so they connect to the correct overworld-side portals.

Note, when I started I wasn't aware that the Y-coordinate mattered; I figured the proximity thing was only based on x and z coordinates.

Anyways, first I built an overworld portal at -16, 196, 163. It's three wide so the actual portal blocks are -15/-16/-17, 196, 163. I then went into the nether via another portal and built one at -2, 51, 20. When they're both lit, they connect properly and no other portals collide. Praise the miners!

(The overworld portal would take me to the spawn chunks, you see.) Next I set out to build an Iron Foundry (Ethos' design, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-Je3IpC1aY).) It requires a small nether portal, which wound up needing to be placed at -14, 184, 210/209. I figured, build another portal at -2, 51, and 26 to make them line up nicely.

No digs. Now the nether side of the spawn chunks portal takes me to the over side of the iron foundry portal, and the overworld side of the spawn chunks portal takes me to the nether side of the iron foundry. Both iron foundry portals link to each other.

summary of portal locations:

overworld:

- spawn chunks: -16, 196, 163
- iron foundry: -14, 184, 210

nether:

- spawn chunks: -2, 51, 20
- iron foundry: -2, 51, 26

My actual question: where can I move my nether portals so they work properly? I can move the spawn chunks portals if need be, but the iron foundry overworld portal needs to be there (otherwise I might as well scrap the whole project.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I know that I have to place them over 1024 for them to naturally link properly, but I was under the impression that you could line them up artificially they would work. As pointed out in one of the solutions, I have divided the X and Z coordinates by 8 to get the proper horizontal positions.

Comment: Have you now lined up the Y co-ords too?

Comment: Set them both at y=184? Could do. I'll try that.